# Adding bottom padding to every cell in a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give a bottom padding to every cell in a table. Since i am using multiple tables in my code, i am using a class by the name summary.

The HTML code is :

```
        <table class="summary">
          <tr>
            <td >...</td> 
            <td>...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

The smarty code is :

```
        <style>
            chargesSummary td {
                padding-bottom:12px;
            }
        </style>
```

I have also tried

```
        <style>
            td.chargesSummary  {
                padding-bottom:12px;
            }
        </style>
```

Only code that adds bottom padding is:

```
        <style>
            td  {
                padding-bottom:12px;
            }
        </style>
```

but it adds to every table cell. I just want to add that for a specific table'e cells.

Comment: Have you tried, `.summary td`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `table.summary td` to select only `td` tags that are descendants of `table`s with the class `summary`.

**CSS**

```
table.summary td  {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```